# Download and run files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

1. I want to download 2 files from: example.com/somefile.jpg and example.com/somefile.bat.
2. Run both files using PowerShell in the bat executable script.

It would be nice if anyone can help by showing an example with the code.

Comment: SO is not a free script writing service. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what particular problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It would be nice if you would show your attempts with errors in the code so we can help with that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service

Comment: Next time I'll ask differently, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer part of your question:

Using **Invoke-WebRequest** you can feed it a url and use the parameter **-OutFile** to send it somewhere locally on your machine, example:

```
$url = example.com/somefile.jpg
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile C:\output\somefile.jpg
```

This will download the somefile.jpg from example.com and save it in C:\output\ on your machine

https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: If the answer is incorrect please go ahead and mark the suggest as not useful or suggest a different approach. Furthermore could you point me in the direction of where it states not to answer such posts, thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I see the argument of answering well asked questions and taken that on board, however it doesn't state to not answer at all. I hope I have aided Cyber Punk in at least the right direction to go with his original question. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: *"Not all questions can or should be answered here. [...]"*

Comment: _"Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which..."_  - It was no frustration for me, I understood his requirements and provided a basis to start on, I am just trying to help :)

Comment: In general, it's better to guide a querent to developing xir own answer, rather than handing xir a solution. Xe might eat for a day, but xe'll be back tomorrow asking for another fish. If you teach xir to fish, xe might be back, but if xe is, xe'll probably be teaching others to fish.

Comment: Thanks everyone for advice and support :))) next time I'll ask differently.